# ListView changing background automatically

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` in which i load an image from the server inside an `ImageView` object and then set my layout object background to be this imageview (the row list background). However, as i scroll the list my background for each row changes and is not fixed. How can i make the background not to change when i scroll.

**MyArrayAdapter.java**

```
@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
    }

    ImageView imageBackground = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageBKG);

    RelativeLayout rowmall = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_mallx);
    rowmall.setBackground(imageBackground.getDrawable());

    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mall.iconWide, imageBackground, Utility.displayImageOptions);

    return convertView;
  }
```

**row_listview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/row_mallx"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="155dp">

     ......
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageBKG"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: grrr why the votedown with no explanation

Comment: Not my downvote, but can you explain what you mean exactly when you say "make the background not to change when i scroll"?

Comment: @Sufian I meant that say the bkg color of item 1 is yellow and item 2 is green when i scroll the bkg color of item 2 becomes green etc

Comment: Not clear yet. Is there an assumption that item 2 wasn't on screen before you started scrolling? Do you want to start load the bg image/colour only when there's no scrolling?

Comment: @Sufian it has to do something with listview recyling the view item. Basically on scrolling the background colors interchange. So say if listview #7 which is not visible on screen comes down it bg color changes to listview #1 when it is shown on screen

Comment: I have seen many guys facing same problem, I guess it's because you may be using `CustomAdapter`

Comment: Try use view holder pattern and your problem will be resolved

Comment: @stud91 hmm. I guess you want to disable showing incorrect bg colour (previous row's bg) when the row is reused. Am I correct?

Comment: @stud91 could you tell me if my comment above was correct?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue so I set my display option like this:

```
displayImageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true).showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.placeholder).cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build();
```

check your display image option

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mall.iconWide, imageBackground, displayImageOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you're facing currently is that when reusing the row, the background of previous view is shown till its actual bg is fetched from the internet.

After `ImageView imageBackground = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageBKG);`, add following line:

```
imageBackground.setImageResource(0);    //this will empty the previously set bg
```

Comment: this makes all backgrounds in the list to be empty (white)

Comment: Write the line I wrote before that, not replace it. You misread :)

Comment: that is exactly what i did..write it before

Comment: nope it doesn't..still the background keeps on changing like before

Comment: I need to verify we're on right track. The problem is that when the row is reused (for example, row 1 is reused to display row 9), the bg of the older row is shown till the new row's actual bg is loaded. Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71066/discussion-between-sufian-and-stud91).

Comment: @stud91 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.